# SlideToggle Jquery: Make active div stand out on website load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have the current script setup as below. It contains three buttons which all toggle a SlideToggle on the div it is linked to. The div that is opened gets an active class, making it stand out by making the button fully orange.

As can be seen, Testdiv 2 is open when the 'website' loads. What I am trying to achieve is to make the button 2 be fully orange when the script loads, and make it lose its active class when another div is selected like what happens when I perform the other button toggles. How can I ensure that this button starts as a orange button, and will be incorporated in the active effect afterwards.

Thanks in advance!

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Lryqt6ou/1/

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    //Start of Jquery

 $('#button1').click(function(){
  if ($('.product').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.product').slideToggle('slow');
        }
        
     $('.developers').slideUp();
     $('.lockedin').slideUp();  
   });

 $('#button2').click(function(){
   if ($('.lockedin').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.lockedin').slideToggle('slow');
    }
    $('.product').slideUp();
    $('.developers').slideUp();   
});

 $('#button3').click(function(){
  if ($('.developers').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.developers').slideToggle('slow');
    }
     $('.product').slideUp();
     $('.lockedin').slideUp();
   });
  
    $(function() {
      $( '.oval' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).parent().find( '.oval.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      });
});

    // End of Jquery
});
```

```css
.oval {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #fa8d37;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  text-indent: 2px;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background: #ffffff; 
  text-transform: uppercase: 
}

.oval:hover {
  background: #fa8d37;
}

.oval.active {
  background: #fa8d37;
  text-transform: uppercase: 
}

.product {
  display:none;
  color: black;
}

.lockedin {
  color:black;
}

.product_active{
  display:none;
  }

.developers {
  display:none;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="oval" id="button1">BUTTON 1</div>

<div class="oval" id="button2"> BUTTON 2</div>

<div class="oval" id="button3">BUTTON 3</div>

<div class="product">
 Testdiv1
 </div>
 
 <div class= "lockedin">
 Testdiv2
 </div>
 
 <div class = "developers">
 Testdiv3
 </div>
```

Comment: Just use <div class="oval active" id="button2"> BUTTON 2</div> maybe? The active class gets added to the button2 by default and when you click on any other div, it gets changed.

Comment: Was struggeling to get this, but you got me there. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No problem at all :)